# Config apache + PDFlib + wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, pdflib

I'm having trouble installing PDFlib in my apache to use in my wordpress application.

I followed the tutorial [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdf.installation.php)

I still did the following command, because I thought in another doubt about the installation:

```
echo "katleia.com.br localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
sudo a2enconf fqdn
```

It is katleia.com.br/worpress the route I put on my browser to access my page.

However when I give the command:

```
service apache2 restart
```

It's the next exit with error:

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/fqdn.conf:
Invalid command 'katleia.com.br', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Can someone help me configure PDFlib? because I'm about four hours trying to make it work in wordpress and has nothing to right.

Already I leave on notice not want to install a wordpress plugin.

**UPDATE**

To undo this command:

```
echo "katleia.com.br katleia" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
```

**UPDATE2**

I managed to make him stop giving error but still does not work.

I did the following command in order to be able to restart the server:

```
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf
sudo a2enconf fqdn
service apache2 restart
```

with this my server returned to work, I added this code in a php file that is named after the click on a button to test:

```
try{
    $pdf = new PDFlib();
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>";
} finally {
  // open a file 
    pdf_open_file($pdf, "test.pdf"); 
    // start a new page (A4) 
    pdf_begin_page($pdf, 595, 842); 
    // get and use a font object 
    $arial = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1); 
    pdf_setfont($pdf, $arial, 10); 
    // print text 
    pdf_show_xy($pdf, "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio,",50, 750); 
    pdf_show_xy($pdf, "than are dreamt of in your philosophy", 50,730); 
    // end page 
    pdf_end_page($pdf); 
    // close and save file 
    pdf_close($pdf);
}
```

He did not have any error, but when I try the file do not find anywhere.

**UPDATE3**

There is this command which in theory was to get an output showing that the PDFlib is running but it does not show anything when I do it on my prompt:

```
# php -i |grep PDF
PDFlib
PDFlib Support => enabled
PDFlib GmbH Binary-Version => 7.0.5p3
```

I could do this part to work was forgetting to add the `extension = pdf.so` the file `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. After I restarted the apache and he gave the expected output.

But still it does not appear the `test.pdf` anywhere.

**UPDATE4**

```
try {
    $p = new PDFlib();

    /*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
    if ($p->begin_document("", "") == 0) {
        die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
    }

    $p->set_info("Creator", "hello.php");
    $p->set_info("Author", "Rainer Schaaf");
    $p->set_info("Title", "Hello world (PHP)!");

    $p->begin_page_ext(595, 842, "");

    $font = $p->load_font("Helvetica-Bold", "winansi", "");

    $p->setfont($font, 24.0);
    $p->set_text_pos(50, 700);
    $p->show("Hello world!");
    $p->continue_text("(says PHP)");
    $p->end_page_ext("");

    $p->end_document("");

    $buf = $p->get_buffer();
    $len = strlen($buf);

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Length: $len");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=teste_do_katleia.pdf");
    print $buf;
}
catch (PDFlibException $e) {
    die("PDFlib exception occurred in hello sample:\n" .
    "[" . $e->get_errnum() . "] " . $e->get_apiname() . ": " .
    $e->get_errmsg() . "\n");
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}

$p = 0;

$len = mb_strlen($buf, 'ASCII');
exit();
```

With the above code can generate a pdf and view it on the site, but that's not what I want. What I want is to save it in a folder and then to recover on another page.
Does anyone know what I have to change this code to be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> With the above code can generate a pdf and view it on the site, but that's not what I want. What I want is to save it in a folder

you should check the comment in the line before the begin_document():

```
 /*  open new PDF file; insert a file name to create the PDF on disk */
if ($p->begin_document("", "") == 0) {
```

in addition you should check the the **PDFlib 7 Tutorial, chapter 3.1.4** "Generating PDF Documents in Memory" for more details on this.

Hint: when creating files on disc, you can not use get_buffer(), which get the the PDF data from memory. (Please consult the API reference, which is also included in your PDFlib 7 package within the doc directory)